# Moving arrays from a resultSet

Tags: java, database, arrays, resultset

I am stuck with trying to implement my little JFrame. Basically I am trying to build an array from a resultSet that connects to a database and when the JFrame is called the little frame populates the array with data from the database.

Here is the complete code I have constructed as I have asked around and no one has a solution for me :( and surely in java this must be a routine request as it is in PHP ect?

Anyway if anyone could please help as it is for my university project which has to be soon, I would be eternally grateful.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainStat extends JPanel {


BufferedImage img;
Double[] eleArray;
private Image bg;
private Image pic;
int alt_1 = normalise(eleArray[0]);
int alt_2 = normalise(eleArray[1]);
int alt_3 = normalise(eleArray[2]);
int alt_4 = normalise(eleArray[3]);
int alt_5 = normalise(eleArray[4]);
int alt_6 = normalise(eleArray[5]);
int alt_7 = normalise(eleArray[6]);
int alt_8 = normalise(eleArray[7]);
int alt_9 = normalise(eleArray[8]);
int alt_0 = normalise(eleArray[9]);
private double shop;
private double bike_shop;
private double accomadation;
int alt = 70;
JLabel label1;
private String display_distance;
static String[] eleResults;

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
static double eleOne;
static double eleTwo;
static double eleThree;
static double eleFour;
static double eleFive;
static double eleSix;
static double eleSeven;
static double eleEight;
static double eleNine;
static double eleZero;


//add in constructor method calling paint(Graphics g)
public mainStat(String distance){
    display_distance = distance;


    label1 = new JLabel();

     setBorder(
             BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                                        BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Geo-strip"),
                                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)),
                        getBorder()));

     add(label1);


}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //main GPS strip 
    try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\test\\geo_strip_box_ex.png"));

           bg = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\test\\geo_strip_main_ex.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    // Primary indicator box
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(20, 45, 75, 60);
    g.drawImage(img, 10, 25, null);
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(display_distance, 16, 80);


    // Main Geo-data
    g.drawImage(bg, 10, 25, null);

    // Altitude data
    // Point 1
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(105, alt_1, 10, 10);

    // Point 2
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(153, alt_2, 10, 10);

    // Point 3
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(201, alt_3, 10, 10);

    // Point 4
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(249, alt_4, 10, 10);

    // Point 5
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(297, alt_5, 10, 10);

    // Point 6
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(345, alt_6, 10, 10);

    // Point 7
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(394, alt_7, 10, 10);

    // Point 8
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(442, alt_8, 10, 10);

    // Point 9
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(490, alt_9, 10, 10);

    // Point 10
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(540, alt_0, 10, 10);

    // Performance blocks that are build out of an array
    //first block
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(108, 144, 108, 12);

    //second block
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(218, 144, 108, 12);

    //third block
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillRect(329, 144, 108, 12);

    //forth block
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(439, 144, 108, 12);
}
    private int normalise(double altitude){
        //Build the array once correct this part will be changed to allow data base connectivity

                ;
        //Next stage is to find the max values within the array
        double max = eleArray[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (eleArray[i]> max) max = eleArray[i];


        //Replicate the double loop control for the min values
        double min = eleArray[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (eleArray[i]< min) min = eleArray[i];

        //Now set the normalised scale; first with the minimum and then the maximum
        double minNalt = 50;
        double maxNalt = 120;

        double result = maxNalt+(altitude-min)*(minNalt-maxNalt)/(max-min);
        int aInt = (int)result;
        return aInt;
    }
        public void Result() {

        String query = "SELECT trkpt_ele FROM routes where trkseg_name = '2011-06-14'";
        try
        {
          // Connect to the database
          //  Similar to php first I need to create a variable to connect to the MySQL database.
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bicycleinformationschema"; 

          // Now we need to include username and pass and test mysql database connection
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "kop98mnbvcxz");

          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
          ArrayList <Double> eleResults = new ArrayList<Double>();

          while (rs.next())

              eleResults.add(rs.getDouble(1));
              Double[] eleArray = eleResults.toArray(new Double[0]);


          }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
          System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

      }
}
```

I really hope someone can help,

thanks

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Try to be more specific then the obvious "it doesnt work"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should respect indentation and Java naming conventions, if you expect some seasoned programmer to read it (we are human, not compilers ;))

The problem: as far as I can understand, you are keeping the results in a local variable, but you are doing nothing with it, it's going nowhere.

Comment: I am trying to learn as I am new to java so please take my apology for my human code trying to mimic a seasoned java programmers code :S

Comment: opps i was meant to add, so how can I call the results and use them properly?

Comment: @PatrickMcGee, I suggest you to return the result array in `Result` method (please, rename it as `getResult`, you will be following conventions and state more clearly its purpose), you will avoid current confusion with duplicated `eleArray`. Then just call `getResult` from main method and assign result to `eleArray`. And please, forget about all these `alt_*`, that's nonsense, you already have an array! Use that array directly in `paintComponent`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think your problem is one of ordering.  You're populating the `alt_*` variables when the class is initialised based on the `eleArray` - yet that array only gets populated when the `Result()` method is called.

By definition that method has to happen after the class is initialised (you can't get a reference to an unconstructed instance of a class) so there's no way those variables can reflect the database lookup.

I'd say that your code could do with some refactoring to reduce the amount of *fields* it uses; instead replace them with local variables in methods when you want to use them.  This will be less prone to ordering issues, and moreover will make your code *much* easier to understand.  You probably only need to keep a reference to the array of points, and maybe some GUI stuff (there's definitely no reason why the `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` for example should be class-level fields).

In fact I've just looked through your code and you only need two fields as it stands:

- the `displayDistance`, which is (correctly) a constructor argument
- A reference to the normalised results of the database query

Everything else is either unused or is only used within a single method.

---

Your database code looks correct to me (well, you're rebuilding the `eleArray` array each time round the loop, which seems superfluous but harmless).

Typical use of a JDBC result set would indeed take the form:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("...");
List<MyDomainClass> results = new ArrayList<MyDomainClass>();

while (rs.next()) {
    MyDomainClass obj;
    // create obj by querying rs for this row

    results.add(obj);
}
```

and that's what you're doing here, by pulling out the `double` from each row and adding it to `eleResults`.

Comment: `eleArray` doesn't get populated, it's a local variable with same name what gets populated. I agree with you, this code needs refactoring to see things clearer.

Comment: @jglatre Ah - you're right of course.  Strong real-world evidence to show that the code could really use some clearing up, and that even "harmless" unused variables should be culled for clarity.